Quasiconformal map for a twist
Consider a surface $X$ and a curve $\gamma$ in its pants decomposition. Consider a twist in this curve by $\tau$ to get a surface $X'$. I know there is a quasiconformal map $f:X\to X'$ (actually there is one minimizing its quasiconformal constant). I'd like to have a bound for the quasiconformal constant I could get from a quasiconformal map. For that matter I'd like to construct a qc map from one to the other, any idea of how such a map should look like?
I had the idea of considering a tubular neighborhood of $\gamma$ and make $f$ to be the identity outside that nbd, inside it I was thinking it should look like $$(r,\theta)\to (r,\theta+ \tau\cdot g(r))$$
where $g$ is zero on the boundary of the tubular nbd and one in $\gamma$. But I ignore if my intuition is mistaken and I am missing something of what a twist in this context should be doing.
